# New to PHP , protected function error

Tags: php, class, object, protected

So , I'm new to PHP and I know this is an easy question for a lot of you , but I'm not sure about one thing.

If I have this , the new object `$a` and `$d` can't echo the `function foo()` , because it's protected , so it means that only sub classes can use it , OBJECT can't? 
It's a bit confusing for me.

Sorry if it's a stupid question , but I don't have a php friend to ask this.

```
<?php

    class A {
        protected function foo(){
            echo "AAA";
        }
    }

    class D extends A { }

    $a = new A();
    $d = new D();
    $a->foo();
    $d->foo();
?>
```

Comment: It can only be called from within the class that owns it or a class that extends it.

Private functions can be called only from within the class that owns it.

Public functions can be called globally like you are trying to do above

Comment: Suggested read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

> because it's protected , so it means that only sub classes can use it , OBJECT can't?

**object** is **instance** of **class**. These are NOT equivalent.

For your question - only `public` methods are reachable from **outside**. So you cannot `$d->foo()` but i.e. `D` class can have public method `x()` which would just do `$this->foo()` and that would work as `x` is part of the class, so it's allowed to reach `protected` element.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. This is how it will wwork.

```
class A {
    protected function foo(){
        echo "AAA";
    }
}

class D extends A {
    public function foo2() {
        $a = new A();
        $a->foo();
    }
 }

//$a = new A();
$d = new D();
//$a->foo();
$d->foo2();
```

Comment: instead of $a = new A(); $a->foo(); just go with $this->foo(); since it's extended

Comment: Yes i agree. That is also possible